# Starting up a Live Server via live-server command not working: env: node\r: No such folder or file

Tags: npm-live-server

I ran command from my terminal "live-server public", since my public folder within my project root folder contains index.html, which is the entry point for my web application. However, I am getting the error "env: node\r: No such file or directory". However, I do have the public folder, so what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue (Mac OS Big Sur, 11.6.5), and I discovered that the issue appears for `live-server` 1.2.2. If you downgrade to version 1.2.1 everything should be fine.
Hope that helps!